# When does make sense to automatically fill a search box?

Tags: website-design, search

On every Stack Exchange site, when somebody clicks on a user link, the search box is automatically filled with a string that would allow to search posts written by that user.

[image: screenshot]

In which cases does automatically filling the search field make sense? Should I just consider if searching is a common operation, or are there other considerations to make?

I was thinking to implement such functionality on a Drupal site, for the user profile pages, or the node pages. In the first case, the search box would be pre filled with a search term that allows searching for nodes (content) written by that user; in the second case, the search box would be filled with a search term that allows searching for similar nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic fill in of search boxes makes sense when the user have made a selection on a web site. This could be a specific user, a group of users or some other refined part of content. As an example there are 5000+ questions on UX.SE. There are too many questions to browse through, and the user might want to find a specific topic, like website-design.

It the user hits the tag [website-design](/questions/tagged/website-design), it makes perfect sense to add this tag to the search query within the search box – and the user narrows the search by 90 % to 544 questions.

[image: search result from tag click]

Still too many, but the user can now further refine the search by adding extra search terms, such as the example below we add “windows” and find 43 questions tagged [website-design](/questions/tagged/website-design) having the word windows in the content (or as another tag).

[image: search result refined by keyword windows]

The benefit is that the user intuitively knows that this is the proper way to search for content, and can elaborate further on the next search.

Comment: +1 agreed. The point about aiding refinement of populated filter parameters were the same as I was thinking.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Thanx! It's especially important on flat or tags organized web sites, such as *.SE sites. Users need to find a way to filter content, and what better way than search is there to do it? :-)

Comment: Yes, definitely. But it can be applied to all kinds of searches. Either to easily refine the populated filter, `tag + search param`, or broaden the populated filter, eg. `city + street + street number - street number =  city + street`. It makes it so much quicker for users to setup filter values.

Comment: Just realized that last comment probably doesn't make much sense when reading it, it made sense in my head, and I'm sticking to it! =D

Comment: @AndroidHustle It makes sense, don't worry :-)